# How to start GNOME Wayland session from command line/tty?

Tags: linux, gnome, tty, wayland

I'm experimenting with wayland.

You can start Gnome with X through `startx` command. Is there an way to start Gnome with wayland through some command?

I would like to be able to run Gnome/X on my main display. 
Then switch to display :2 (Ctrl+alt+win+F2/F3) and then run something like:

```
startWayland
```

So that I have a seconday desktop with gnome running with wayland.

Is this possible? (A near-alternative is also welcome)

Comment: I guess it'd be better in https://unix.stackexchange.com/, but I have no idea how to migrate.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A working solution per Jonas Ådahl a mutter developer:

> Usually what I do is switch to a VT and run:
>
> dbus-run-session -- gnome-shell --display-server --wayland

Comment: That seems to work. Is there a way to terminate the session? Logout doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev well, I didn't ask, but I just ran `killall gnome-shell`.

Comment: This didn't work well in Fedora 29 (no start-up apps, couldn't log out).  The answer by soloturn fixes this.

Comment: @Acyclic use `XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland dbus-run-session gnome-session` then.

Answer (score 12):

`XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland dbus-run-session gnome-session`

to force firefox and QT applications as well to wayland, in 2019-12-31 they do not respect XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland:

`MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1 QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland dbus-run-session gnome-session`

if it should log out the command line session after pressing "logout" in the gnome GUI, add an `exec`:
`XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland exec dbus-run-session gnome-session`

From docs: 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME#Wayland_sessions

Comment: In Fedora 28 this is the only answer that actually worked. Thanks!

Comment: I did not thoroughly test it but on the surface it seems to work great for Fedora 38 and XFCE (requires changing `gnome-session` to `xfce4-session`).

Answer (score 7):

Never mind, I found the solution:

```
gnome-session --session gnome-wayland
```

Source:
GNOME / Wayland in Fedora | Goings on
https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2013/10/03/gnome-wayland-in-fedora/

[EDIT]
This no longer seems to work with recent fedora (24). At the moment I haven't found a solution for this. The only way I get Wayland working these days is to use the gear at login and set the system to log into wayland. If anyone has a solution to this...

Answer (score 1):

Note that the following video drivers do not work with Wayland: nvidia, cirrus, Hi1710.

I discovered this after several days of trying to get Wayland to work with my Nvidia video device until I saw this comment buried in the ArchLinux Wiki for GDM. [ArchLinux GDM Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM)

The file that controls this is /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules

This script sets /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-disable-wayland which tells gdm not to show the /usr/share/wayland-sessions on the session menu for these device drivers.  (I am using Ubuntu Focal/20.04)

I was able to get Wayland working by uninstalling the nvidia drivers, and although  I was pleased to get it working I went back to using the X/Nvidia setup as I preferred the smoother look and performance.